# Creación de registro nuevo en Angular y spring

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http-post

estoy tratando de crear un registro nuevo en Angular y Spring pero al crear un nuevo registro me crear con datos nulos y no con los datos ingresados en los inputs , ya importe HttpClientModule en mi module y en mi servicio importe HttpClient,HttpHeaders , ¿por que ser crear nulos?
al probar enviar los datos ingresados de los inputs a consola , si me reciven y se muestra en consola , pero al conectarlo con spring se crean datos nulos creados en  la base de datos

este es mi código spring , metodo Post para crear un Cliente nuevo

```
@PostMapping("/crearCliente")
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
   public Cliente create(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {
       cliente.setCLI_REGIS(new Date());
       return clienteServicio.save(cliente);
```

este es mi código en Angular:

este es mi clase cliente :

```
export class Cliente{
    CLI_ID:number;
    CLI_NOM:String;
    CLI_APELL:String;
    CLI_EMAIL:String;
    CLI_REGIS:String;
}
```

Importo HttpClientModule en app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListarComponent } from './listar/listar.component';
import { ClienteComponent } from './cliente/cliente.component';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import {ClienteService} from './cliente/cliente.service';
import { CrearComponent } from './crear/crear.component';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


const rutas:Routes=[
  {path:'',component:ClienteComponent},
  {path:'listar',component:ListarComponent},
  {path:'crear',component:CrearComponent},
  {path:'**',component:ClienteComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListarComponent,
    ClienteComponent,
    CrearComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rutas)
  ],
  providers: [ClienteService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

importo HttpClient en mi servicio

```
import { ImplicitReceiver } from '@angular/compiler';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {Cliente} from './cliente';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ClienteService{
    
    private url : string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/cli/listar';
    private urlcrear :string ='http://localhost:8080/api/cli/crearCliente';

    private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-type':'application/json'})

    constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    }

    getClientes():Observable<Cliente[]>{

        return this.http.get<Cliente[]>(this.url);
    }

    create(cliente:Cliente): Observable<Cliente>{
        return this.http.post<Cliente>(this.urlcrear,cliente,{headers:this.httpHeaders});
    }
}
```

llamo al servicio en el crear.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Cliente } from '../cliente/cliente';

import {ClienteService} from '../cliente/cliente.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crear',
  templateUrl: './crear.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crear.component.css']
})
export class CrearComponent implements OnInit {

   public cliente:Cliente= new Cliente;

   public titulo:String="Crear Cliente"

  constructor(public clienteService:ClienteService ,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public create():void{
    this.clienteService.create(this.cliente).subscribe(
      response => this.router.navigate(['/listar'])
    )
  }

}
```

routerLink en los inputs

```
<div class="container">

    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>{{titulo}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">

            <label class="col-md-2">Nombre</label>
            <input class="col-md-6 form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="cliente.CLI_NOM">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">

            <label class="col-md-2">Apellido</label>
            <input class="col-md-6 form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="cliente.CLI_APELL">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">

            <label class="col-md-2">Email</label>
            <input class="col-md-6 form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="cliente.CLI_EMAIL">

        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <button class="btn-success" role="button" (click)="create()">Crear</button>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

crea solo null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya probaste si  la API funciona bien? insertando datos sin usar Angular.

Comment: sí , lo probé con Postman y ingresa bien los datos

Comment: Y la petición generada por Angular lleva el formato y los datos correctos?

Comment: si , la estoy heredando de mi clase cliente , ahora la acabo de agregar a la pregunta

Comment: El código se ve bien, has revisado la  petición en el navegador en las herramientas de desarrollo?

Comment: si , estoy utilizando Chrome , pero no me lanza error también :( , ¿Cual seria el error?

Comment: Me refiero a revisar en la pestaña de network, donde aparece la petición y se puede ver toda la información como sus cabeceras, contenido , etc.

Comment: si se refiere a ver en console los datos , si envían y se pueden visualizar

Comment: Para quedar claros me refiero a ver la información aquí https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/imgs/network.png en la pestaña network

Comment: no me muestra nada , solo linea verde que se en forma horizontal

Comment: Si la petición se ve, puedes darle clic para ver su información y ahí revisar el contenido de la petición. Para salir de dudas si angular está funcionando bien.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que estés enviando nulos al backend, puedes ver lo que estas enviando en las herramientas de desarrollo como ya te explicaron.

Answer (score 0):

puedes sacarnos de la duda a varios haciendo lo siguiente en tu servicio de creación. Agregando un **console.log**, con esto veríamos en la consola del navegador lo que estas enviando al endpoint de creación.

```
create(cliente:Cliente): Observable<Cliente>{
        console.log('cliente', cliente)
        return this.http.post<Cliente>(this.urlcrear,cliente,{headers:this.httpHeaders});
    }
```

Compartenos que muestra la consola y ya dependiendo de lo que veamos allí podríamos hacer un mejor diagnostico.

Answer (score 0):

Spring te convierte el JSON a Java Object si las propiedades del JSON coincide con las de la clase Java. Como te han dicho arriba comprueba qué recibe y, para asegurar el casteo de forma correcta, añade esto dentro delante del objeto en la función:
`@ModelAttribute("nombreClase)` . De esta forma le dices a Spring que debe recibir un objeto nombreClase.